# Filter DataFrame by Float column values in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I need to filter values in Spark dataFrame column according to the datatype. I want to have only float numbers in a column. I tried to use some regular expressions, however, I get an error while writing to csv file: `SparkException: Task not serializable`

Here is the method which reads from CSV file into dataFrame, then I filter some of the columns and write them back to the csv file:

```
def processDatasetCsvWithSpark(sqlContext: SQLContext, columnNames: Seq[String], filename: String, dfSchema: StructType,
                                 inputFilepath: String, outputFilepath: String) = {
    val testDf = sparkNeo4jWriteBenchmarks.readFromCsvToDfWithCustomSchema(sqlContext, filename, inputFilepath, dfSchema)

    val renamedColsDf = testDf.toDF(columnNames: _*)

    val filteredBioDF = renamedColsDf.withColumn("bio", regexp_replace(renamedColsDf("bio"), forbiddenSymbols, "")).dropDuplicates()

    val filteredFloatDF: DataFrame = filteredBioDF.filter( df => numberRegex.pattern.matcher(filteredBioDF.select("lat:FLOAT").toString()).matches)
    filteredFloatDF
      .write
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .save(outputFilepath + filename + ".csv")
  }
```

Without this filteredFloatDF calculation, DataFrame is written without any problems. So how can I filter my DataFrame column by the Float datatype or number regular expressions effectively without such errors?

Comment: what do you mean by `I want to have only float numbers in a column`? a column would have only one datatype either its float or something else. are you looking to select only the float columns?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan the problem is while writing the file some columns get moved and instead of the float numbers in a column, there may be some string values. How can I check it?

Comment: what do you mean by get moved? if a column has string values then the columns schema should be string and not float.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use `cast()` to cast the column into `FloatType`, essentially converting all the non-float values into null:

```
// CSV file content:
// id,value
// 1,50
// 2,null
// 3,60.5
// 4,a

val df = spark.read.
  option("header", true).
  csv("/path/to/csvfile")

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df2 = df.withColumn("val_float", $"value".cast(FloatType))
// +---+-----+---------+
// | id|value|val_float|
// +---+-----+---------+
// |  1|   50|     50.0|
// |  2| null|     null|
// |  3| 60.5|     60.5|
// |  4|    a|     null|
// +---+-----+---------+
```

You can re-cast the FloatType column back to StringType, if necessary.